# Error while connecting to oracle database in windows server 2012

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g, odbc, windows-server-2012

I am trying to make a call to DLL which is "Microsoft.data.odbc.dll" and its failing in windows server 2012. I have oracle 11 G client installed in the server.

Error Message :

> RROR [NA000] [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]Error while
>   trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019ERROR [IM006]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr
>   failedERROR [01000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The driver
>   doesn't support the version of ODBC behavior that the application
>   requested (see SQLSetEnvAttr). -    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Open()   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior)   at
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)

Note : Its working in my local box which has windows 7 and Oracle Client 11G.

Comment: If you have the oracle client installed then you should be calling the oci.dll not the odbc driver

Comment: in the latest versions of Windows there are two versions of ODBC Administrator: x86 and x64. You need to use the latter for .Net app on the server. As a result you need to install the x64 drivers for Oracle, including the Instant Client